# Read text file char by char

Tags: c++, file-io

I've tried code from several other questions/tutorials, always getting whitespace or nothing back.

in.txt:

```
a
z
```

main.cpp:

```
ifstream in (argv[1]);
in.open(argv[1]);
if (!in.is_open()) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
char c;
in >> c;
cout << c;
```

Doesn't pass anything back to `cout`, as though there is no character. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to re-open an already-opened file without freeing the resource before thus putting it into an unconsistent state

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/ifstream/

```
#include<fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char*argv[]){

  std::ifstream in ("mytext.txt");
  char c;
  in >> c;
  cout << c;

  in.open("mytext.txt");

  if(!in.good())
    cout << "unconsistent state!";

  return 0;

}
```

> If the object already has a file associated (open), the function
>   fails.

Comment: AH! I did not realise `ifstream file (to_open)` actually opened it. Thank you. (will accept in 4min..)

Comment: But `in.good()` isn't the way to check for this.  Idiomatically: `if ( in ) //...`, or if you want to be more specific, `if ( in.fail() )...`.

Comment: "Returns true if none of the stream's error state flags (eofbit, failbit and badbit) is set.", is exactly what you should be checking for since the failbit would be set

Answer (score 1):

To read a file char-by-char, while respecting input text formatting, you can use the following:

```
if (in.is_open())
    char c;
    while (in.get(c)) {
        std::cout << c;
    }
}
```

where `in` is an input stream of type `std::ifstream`. You can open such a file, like so: `std::ifstream in('myFile.txt');`

This is an unbeffered read. Buffered reads are typically preferred (eg. line-by-line).